# Subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, abelian-groups

I hope that the following problem isn't actually elementary (at least, for the sake of the fact that I'm posting it here), and I apologize if it is.  I did try hard to solve it first.

Let $V$ be a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector subspace of $\mathbb{Q}^n$, and let $G = V \cap \mathbb{Z}^n$.
Does there exist a linearly independent generating set for $G$ (i.e. a subset of $G$ such that every element of $G$ can be expressed uniquely as as $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of elements of this subset)?
Is there an algorithm to find it (given a basis for $V$)?

Comment: It's indeed too elementary, any subgroup of a free abelian group is free, i.e. it has a basis. As for the method to find it, that depends on what you know about $V$.

Comment: @Fernando Muro: I agree regarding the first part, but do not understand what you mean by "know about V"; it says in OP "given a basis for V".

Comment: @quid I didn't see it. Take the basis of $V$, compute a system of linear equations for $V$ with respect to the standard basis of $\mathbb Q$. The same equations define $G$ over the standard basis of $\mathbb Q$. Now, apply the Smith normal form algorithm to obtain a basis for $G$.

Comment: Fernando: it is too elementary if you were taught these things. So is the fact that every left invertible element of the group von Neumann algebra of a discrete group is invertible (because every projection in a vN algebra with faithful finite trace is of finite type, I'm sure Aaron can explain this better than me)

Comment: If you take this question to math.stackexchange, you will get a more detailed answer, I expect.

Comment: Chris: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3405/is-a-subgroup-of-a-free-abelian-group-free-abelian would suffice, at least for the first part

Comment: I learnt this in my first undergraduate year at the university. Definitely not a research level question.

Comment: Fernando: well, your university 1st year went further than mine, I guess.

Comment: @Aaron: not that it will make much difference, but I suppose you could always explain the (K_0 flavoured?) background that led you to this question.

Comment: You don't know the Smith normal form and you know $K_0$? Impressive.

Comment: I hope my question didn't offend you Fernando.  I was tentative about asking it, because I wasn't sure if it was research-level.  Perhaps, sometimes you need to see the answer before you realize how easy a question is.  Thank you for pointing out Smith Normal Form, since I didn't learn about it in my undergrad or graduate career

Comment: It seems this thread has a meta page now.  http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1537/an-elementary-question-thoughts/

Comment: @Aaron Tikuisis no offence, I simply think it doesn't fit this forum.

Comment: Please don't upvote this question anymore.

Comment: I was surprised to log in to MO to be told that I've earned a "Nice Question" badge.  My reason for feeling, at the time of posting, that this question might be unreasonable is that I had thought seriously about it for a day or so, and it felt like the sort of question that is either nontrivial or could be solved in that amount of time.  In retrospect, I really should have found the answer to my first question using Wikipedia.  (Part of what mislead me was thinking that the special form of $G$ could be important - it isn't an arbitrary subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^n$.)

Comment: I might mention that, although I have some regrets about posting the question in this form (mainly that it makes me look bad), I wouldn't feel the same had I done the internet research and then asked simply about an algorithm.  (I can only speculate that I wouldn't have found Smith Normal Form on my own in that circumstance.)  Insofar as I got the answer I wanted, I am happy that I asked, though I suppose that people who sneak in questions from their math homework can often say the same.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. It might not be very relevant (since I am pseudonymous and even if I were not we are, for subject-reasons, very unlikely to ever interact, except here) but still let me say that I did not at all get away with a bad impression, rather the opposite.

Comment: @Aaron: Another instance where the Smith normal form is used and which I think is interesting to you is the computation of the K-theory of a Cuntz--Krieger algebra. There, you have to compute the kernel and cokernel of some integer matrix. The result can be read off from the Smith normal form of the matrix.

Answer (score 14):

**EDIT**: I typed this up before everyone piled on to say that this is too elementary. Moving to CW rather than deleting, as I distinctly remember *not* seeing this during my education on groups and rings (but then maybe I missed class that day). And don't even *go* down the line of "grad school courses"...

Feel free to downvote if you feel like it, of course.

---

Interesting question! The following is not a full answer, but seemed worth a bit more than a comment.

If I understand correctly, the first part asks if G is free abelian, in which case the answer is apparently yes, see [this MO question from *someone* reputable](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3405/is-a-subgroup-of-a-free-abelian-group-free-abelian). (I confess this is not something I knew, although I did have my suspicions.)

My guess is that some modification of Gauss-Jordan elimination should provide an algorithm for extracting a "Z-basis" from a Z-generating set, but it's not clear to me right now how one would get a Z-generating set from a given Q-basis of your original V.

Comment: Your "guess" is what is known as the Smith normal form.

Comment: @Felipe, of course you know, but for the record: the Smith normal form algorithm combines Gauss-Jordan ideas with Euclides's algorithm for the gcd. I like to see it as a generalization of the later, rather than the former.

Comment: Yemon, the question you have linked to specifically asks about not necessarily finitely generated free abelian groups. The OP does not need to read the Wikipedia proof for his question, this is much more elementary.